# Loading webpage after some time ASP.net using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

It seems a duplicate but Its taken a lot of time still causing some problem. Kindly someone point out what I am doing wrong.

I have a **button**, when I click it **JS function** **show()** is called

```
<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="Add to Cart">
```

The javascript code is below

```
    function show() {

          document.getElementById("loadingDiv").style.display = "block";

          setTimeout('Redirect()', 2000);
          function Redirect() {
              location.href = 'Index.aspx';
          }


    }
```

The div is set to **block** properly but the **page never redirects**. Not sure whats the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the brackets and the single quotes when you call the `redirect` function.

```
setTimeout(Redirect, 2000);
```

Here is the documentation for the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function.

Comment: Cool Thank you so much :). It wasted a lot of time. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
function show() {

      document.getElementById("loadingDiv").style.display = "block";

      setTimeout(function(){
            location.href = 'Index.aspx';
      }, 2000);

}
```

or create `redirect` function out of `show` function body and call it with name not as string.

Answer (score 0):

change this line `setTimeout('Redirect()', 2000);` to `setTimeout(Redirect(), 2000);`

basically in the setTimeout parameter the function name should not be in Quotes